# image byte stream getting corrupted in android

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an application in android which is used to capture images. It works normally in lots of samsung phones,tablets but on the samsung 2 310(7 inch ics 4.0.3) the byte stream is getting corrupted. I get the following error in logcat .

```
09-26 16:50:49.044: E/CameraHAL(99): (1494458)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1703 setState - Adapter state switch INTIALIZED_STATE Invalid Op! event = 0x5

09-26 16:55:21.279: E/CameraHAL(99): (1494458)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1786 setState - Adapter state switch PREVIEW_ACTIVE Invalid Op! event = 0x5

09-26 16:55:14.912: E/CameraHAL(99): (14e30e8)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXFocus.cpp:209 doAutoFocus - Autofocus callback timeout expired


09-26 16:55:15.279: E/CameraHAL(99): (14e30e8)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1059 notifyShutterSubscribers - Sending shutter callback

09-26 16:57:36.380: E/CameraHAL(99): (14d4c10)   hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/OMXCameraAdapter/OMXFocus.cpp:209 doAutoFocus - Autofocus callback timeout expired.
```